# Existe um atalho de teclado para alternar entre o terminal e o editor no VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Eu sei que o atalho `Ctrl + Shift + '` abre o terminal e se já estiver aberto ele transfere o cursor de digitação para o terminal, porém eu gostaria de um atalho que alterna entre os dois com mais facilidade, como se fosse um `Alt + Tab` só que entre o editor e o terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Tem um jeito bem simples sim

Vamos fazer um passo a passo.

1 - <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + '</kbd> vai abrir o terminal
2 - <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> vai voltar o cursor para a área do Editor
3 - <kbd>Ctrl + '</kbd> vai sai do Editor e voltar pro Terminar

Resumindo, depois que vc abriu o Terminal é só alternar entre <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl + '</kbd> para ficar jogando o cursor de um para o outro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]